# Cheap hostel around London City Airport

Tags: london, hotels, lcy

Is there any cheap hostel around London City Airport? Preferably the hostel should be reachable by foot.

I would be arriving at the London City Airport at about 8.30pm someday during May, so I am not sure whether by that time the train or railway is still available? Which is by I would insist on hostels are reasonably near to the Airport.

I will be heading off to Canterbury the next day on a train.

If the trains are still operating by 9pm something, I wouldn't mind staying in hostel that is located a bit far away from the airport as long as the hostel is sufficiently near to a railway station that can bring me to Canterbury.

Comment: London city airport is located next to the Canary Wharf area, and is in one of the most expensive London locations.

Comment: There's a Travelodge in good condition next to the airport. If you catch a sale, rooms can be £9-£12. Normal prices can be as low as £19, but as I type this you aren't going to get much change out of £40 until after the summer. During the Olympics, prices are £330.95.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

8 pm isn't really late. You could also go to Canterbury on the day of your arrival, since the last train to Canterbury leaves at 21:50 from City Airport London. [You would arrive at 23:38 in Canterbury](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/London_City_Airport/Canterbury/today/2100/dep).

In London itself, it really depends on where you want to go. But if you check the [Transport for London homepage](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/), you will see that you can get form the City Airport to the center of London almost 24/7.

Nevertheless there are also some hostel or cheap hotels around London City Airport:

- [Globe Trott Inns](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Globe-Trott-Inns/London/56456)
- [Antigallican Hotel](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Antigallican-Hotel/London/18780)
- [Etap Hotel London City Airport](http://www.etaphotel.com/gb/hotel-3578-etap-hotel-london-city-airport-soon-ibis-budget/index.shtml)
- [London City Airport](http://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/294/London-City-Airport-hotel)

Comment: agree with Roflcoptr, however you may want to consider your immigration process in the airport. in my experience it took me 1 - 1.5 hours. You have to run after you finished your immigration, quickly get an oyster card in basement and catch the train. Alternatively you could get your oyster card sent by mail.

Comment: That's true, but however I think immigration time really depends on the actual day. Last time it took me not more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Admittedly only done this as an EU citizen. This is not Heathrow. At LCY you should get through security very quickly. Takes about 10 minutes from touchdown to standing on the DLR platform.